# Yaw, pitch, roll: sample data from ships

Tags: data-request, transportation, time-series, oceanographic

I am looking for sample data describing the yaw, pitch, and roll on a ship:

[image: ship yaw, pitch, roll]

Preferably with frequent sampling (1 per second or more), for at least a minute.

Especially in extreme weather, and especially for large ships like aircraft carriers, but all data is welcome.

*(Image by Jmvolc at en.wikipedia [Public domain], [from Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ARotations.png))*